# Commands from .bashrc not available in Emacs

Tags: emacs, bash

I have some aliases and functions defined in ~/.bashrc.

I start emacs from a terminal window using `emacs -nw`

When I execute `M-x shell-command`, the aliases and functions from ~/.bashrc are not available, but give a "command not found".

I've googled quite a bit but all the  posts I come across say, if I understand them correctly, that ~/.bashrc is the place where this should work (rather than ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aliases are available only in interactive shell - a snapshot from bash man page:

> Aliases are not expanded when the
>   shell is not interactive, unless the
>   expand_aliases shell option is set
>   using shopt
>          (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

Answer (score 2):

If you start Emacs from an interactive shell (in which .bashrc, etc. have executed), then the commands from your .bashrc should be available for both `shell-command` and `shell`, at least that's how it works for me.

But yeah as the other answer says, there is not real way to get a .bashrc environment in emacs. There are some documentation about a .emacs_bash file, but that never worked for me.

---

Okay misread your question here. If you are looking for functions and aliases instead of commands by changing paths in .bashrc, the non-interactiveness is the problem. I guess you can change the default argument to shell-command (take a look at `explicit-bash-args`) to make bash interactive, but that probably has unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393494/1319821) correctly states that "aliases are available only in interactive shell".

This means that in order to load (rightly located indeed) aliases from `~/.bashrc`, an **interactive** shell would have to be launched with `Emacs`'s `M-x shell-command` (`M-!`).

To achieve this, add [`-i`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)  (interactive) switch to the `M-x shell-command` with:

`(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")`

**Side Note**, not `Emacs` related:
On [some operating systems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles) users would need to add the line `source ~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile` (or similar), since `~/.bashrc` is not always auto-read by a system.