# How to make Emacs use my .bashrc file?

Tags: bash, emacs, path

I need to use my `$PATH` in Emacs to run some commands. How can I make Emacs use it? I installed Emacs from Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393400/commands-from-bashrc-not-available-in-emacs

Comment: [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29120/8849) seems to be a perfect resolution.

Comment: [The DotFiles article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles)  covers specifics of bash dot-files load and provides background context for better understanding of the processes discussed in this QA thread.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's a trick [I use](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/init-exec-path.el) to ensure my GUI Emacs always sees the same `$PATH` that I get inside a shell:

```
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  (let ((path-from-shell (replace-regexp-in-string
                          "[ \t\n]*$"
                          ""
                          (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL --login -i -c 'echo $PATH'"))))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq eshell-path-env path-from-shell) ; for eshell users
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))

(when window-system (set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH))
```

Specifically, on OS X, a graphical Emacs will not pick up the user's shell's definition of `$PATH`, so this trick helps me on that platform.

**Update: this code has now been published as an elisp library called [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) and installable packages are available in [MELPA](https://melpa.org/).**

Comment: This fixes the same problem in ubuntu 13.04 (I used the package manager install)

Comment: It does not seem to use aliases. Would not expect it from because of the name though. Is there something for also getting the aliases of normal bash?

Comment: Emacs will never use your bash aliases, sorry: those are only available inside bash sessions. This code and the exec-path-from-shell package simply allow Emacs to reliably locate the same executable files and scripts that are visible in your bash sessions.

Comment: Neither bash functions ? Or do I do somethings wrong ?

Comment: @Welgriv No, functions work like bash aliases, so my comment above applies to them too.

Comment: See [answer by Hugues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036157/1319821) that also covers aliases.

Answer (score 21):

A more general solution (to set all variables and aliases, not just `PATH`) is given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12229404/1190077 -- the key is to set:

```
(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")
```

which overrides the default `"-c"` (execute the following command).  The addition of `"-i"` forces the bash shell into interactive mode, which leads to the sourcing of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Seems to work better than the accepted answer since it allow bash functions using.

Comment: On MacOS, with this setup, I kept everything I had at `~/.bash_profile`, then added line `source ~/.bash_profile` to `~/.bashrc`. As simple as is. Finally my `$PATH` and conveniency aliases available smoothly at `Emacs`'s `M-x shell-command`.

Answer (score 3):

If your env vars aren't picked up it may be due to the way emacs is started. Check the menuitem or whatever and try changing `emacs` to `bash -c emacs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add path settings to /etc/profile.d such as

```
# /etc/profile.d/path.sh
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local"
```

In Ubuntu, I remember all sessions source your `~/.xsessionrc`, so you also can set path in this file for GUI apps.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something similar for sourcing my .bash_profile. If you only care about PATH, one of the other answers above is simpler.

It works by executing `source ~/.bash_profile ; echo post-env; env` then throwing away everything before "post-env", and then parsing out the values in the "key=value" format that the "env" command prints.

It probably doesn't handle every case perfectly, but works well enough for me.

```
;;-------------------------------------------------------
;; begin sourcing of .bash_profile

;; only do this on Mac OS X
(when (string= system-type "darwin")
  ;; require common lisp extensions, for search
  (require 'cl)


  (defun src-shell-unescape (string)
    ;; replace \n \t \r \b \a \v \\
    ;; and octal escapes of the form \0nn

    (replace-regexp-in-string
     "\\\\\\([ntrbav]\\|\\(\\\\\\)\\|\\(0[0-7][0-7]\\)\\)"
     (lambda (str)
       ;; interpret octal expressions
       ;; of the form "\0nn"
       (let ((char1 (aref str 1)))
     (cond ((= ?0 (aref str 1))
        (byte-to-string
         (+ (* (- (aref str 2) ?0) 8)
            (- (aref str 3) ?0))))
           ((eq char1 ?n) "\n")
           ((eq char1 ?t) "\t")
           ((eq char1 ?r) "\r")
           ((eq char1 ?b) "\b")
           ((eq char1 ?a) "\a")
           ((eq char1 ?v) "\v")
           ((eq char1 ?\\) "\\\\")
           (t "")))) string))

  (defun src-set-environment-from-env-output(env-output)
    ;; set the environment from shell's "env" output
    (let ((lines (split-string env-output "\n" t)))
      (dolist (line lines)
    (let ((idx-equals (search "=" line)))
      (when (and (not (eq idx-equals nil))
             (> idx-equals 1))
        (let  ((key (substring line 0 idx-equals))
           (value (substring line (+ idx-equals 1))))
          (setenv key (src-shell-unescape value))
          ;; (message "%s = %s" key value)
          ))))))

  (defun src-source-shell-file (file-name)
    ;; if your shell is sh rather than bash, the "source " may need
    ;; to be ". " instead
    (let* ((command (concat "source '"  file-name "'; echo 'post-env'; env"))
       (output (shell-command-to-string command))
       (idx-post-env (search "post-env" output)))
      (if (eq nil idx-post-env)
      (message "Didn't find expected output after sourcing %s. Found: %s" file-name output)
    (let ((trimmed-output (substring output idx-post-env)))
      ;; (message "trimmed-output: %s" trimmed-output)
      (src-set-environment-from-env-output trimmed-output)))))



  (src-source-shell-file (expand-file-name "~/.bash_profile")))


;; end sourcing of .bash_profile
;;-------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `$PATH` is set in the terminal you launch emacs from, you can execute system commands through the command `M-! <your command> RET`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Emacs packages that update $PATH environment variable and the 'exec-path'.  That's because Emacs don't assume definitions in BASH related files, such as '~/.bashrc'.

All definitions you need to have in any program not executed from a terminal shell, must be moved to '~/.profile', these are loaded in the system startup.

Some old systems need to manually load user profile from '/etc/profile'.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be a comment but the formatting didn't work out.  The answer from @Hueges worked for me except it caused issues with `dired` mode.  Someone with stronger elisp could do better than this, but it worked for me.

```lisp
;; temporarily set shell-command-switch to -ic until function completes
(defun wrap-shell-command (func &rest args) 
  (let ((current-shell-command-switch shell-command-switch)) 
    (setq shell-command-switch "-ic") 
    (apply func args) 
    (setq shell-command-switch current-shell-command-switch)))

;; usage
(wrap-shell-command 'shell-command "func-define-in-bashrc" "other" "args")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;; set shell-command-switch to -ic only for async-shell-command
(defun pre-command-hook-fn ()
  "."
  (if (string= current-minibuffer-command "async-shell-command")
      (setq shell-command-switch "-ic")
    (setq shell-command-switch "-c")
    )
  )

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'pre-command-hook-fn)
```

TODO: Modify 'exec-path' to make minibuffer completion use interactive shell's PATH.