# Emacs: how to tab-complete commands/aliases defined in .bashrc?

Tags: bash, emacs

Is there any (not too intrusive) way to make TAB-completion of aliases defined in ~/.bashrc work within an emacs shell (opened with M-x shell)?

For example, I have defined a command "foo" via alias foo="bar" in .bashrc. I can type "foo" in an emacs shell and execute the command, but I can't just type "fo" + TAB -- it won't be expanded to "foo".

I found [Commands from .bashrc not available in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393400/commands-from-bashrc-not-available-in-emacs) but I'm not sure if this is the definite answer in terms of if it is possible or not. I tried to play with `shopt -s expand_aliases` but not sure where I should put this exactly.

I work with Emacs 24.0.92 (9.0) on Mac OS X 10.7.3. I know that there is an issue about how PATH is set on the Mac, but that's not the problem here. I have precisely the same PATH as in the terminal.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163591/bash-autocompletion-in-emacs-shell-mode has some useful answers?

Comment: Hi Miron. I found bash-completion.el under that hint. That did it, thanks.

Comment: Miron -- you should probably make your answer an answer instead of a comment (so this can be closed) OR close this as a duplicate.