# Emacs, bash, bashrc, functions and paths

Tags: emacs, path, pythonpath, bash

Usually I use my `.bashrc` file to load some functions for my **bash environment**. When I call these functions (that I created based on some frameworks I use). So, I play around with variables such as `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` when I use the functions depending on the environment I'm working on.

So far so well with the terminal. The problem is that when I use **emacs** these functions and these **environmental variables** that I activate with my functions, they don't exist. `.bashrc` is not read by emacs, and therefore I don't have the functions loaded by `.bashrc` don't work. I would like them to work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get my emacs to recognize my bash aliases and custom functions when I run a shell command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224909/is-there-a-way-to-get-my-emacs-to-recognize-my-bash-aliases-and-custom-functions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224909/is-there-a-way-to-get-my-emacs-to-recognize-my-bash-aliases-and-custom-functions), [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393400/commands-from-bashrc-not-available-in-emacs), and [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411121/how-to-make-emacs-use-my-bashrc-file).

Comment: I'm reading the questions and testing. But not working. I crossed some of them before asking my question. :/

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that emacs, as many other programs you run, reads your login shell rc files, such as `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile`, but not `~/.bashrc`, where as your terminal also reads you user shell rc file: `~/.bashrc`.